# Convert urls to clickable links - domain.com/foo/bar

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains some links. I need them converted to clickable links, but the issue is that a lot of these don't start with http or www. How can I convert them without inadvertently affecting the rest of the string?

Sample String: http://pastebin.com/bMe9pGbv

Comment: Does the string only contain multiple URL's or does it contain other words as well ?

Comment: I had tried this: `\b.*?\.(com|net|eu|co\.uk|org)*.?\b` but it doesn't appear to be detecting the word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to isolate all the links from the text. We assume that links don't have spaces, so we create an array with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) using the space as the delimiter:

```
$rows = explode(' ', $text);
```

Then, from each row, we identify the link, add `http://` (if it is missing) and add the `<a>` tag:

```
foreach ($rows AS $key => $row) {
    if (preg_match("@^[^\.\n]+\.[^ \n]+$@", $row)) {
        if (!preg_match('@^http://@', $row)) {
            $row = 'http://' . $row;
        }

        $rows[$key] = '<a href="'.$row.'">'.$row.'</a>';
    }
}
```

Finally, we rebuild the text, using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and the `space` as the delimiter:

```
$text = implode(' ', $rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my solution for detecting actual URL (starting with a scheme) and replacing it with `<a>`.

```
<?php
echo preg_replace(
    "/(http:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|https:\/\/)([^\s,]*)/i",
    "<a href=\"$1$2\">$1$2</a>",
    $input
);
```

Detecting arbitrary clickable links not starting with scheme requires way more complicated regex and more guessworks.